# chapter image resizing

Tags: header-footer, chapters, books

I am trying to make a book in LaTeX. To the table of contents I want to add a image to the title. The problem is that the image is so long, that it reaches until almost half of the page. Is there a way to resize the image (just the lenght)?

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\chapterimage{image1.png} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontent
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE does not compile. What does the `\chapterimage` macro do? Please try to make your MWE compile.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: `\chapterimage` is a command of the dreadful `Legrand Orange Book template`, which requires the inclusion of a `structure.tex` file, which isn't done here ... there might be other templates/packages/classes that have `\chapterimage` as well, but you're right: this 'MWE' can't be compiled

Comment: Here is the [Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! It's quite pretty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are, as Christian Hupfer said, using the `Dreadful Legrand Orange Book template` then adding this to your preamble should do what you want:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makeschapterhead
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=4.13333in]{\thechapterimage}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

The `height=4.13333in` was taken from the `chapter_head_1.pdf`, which is included in the template zip. Adjust it at your will.

Comment: The title isn't `Dreadful ....` -- that's only my name for it :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know. But I think it has more... Impact with the `Dreadful` :P

Comment: Yes, I forgot the structure.tex code. Thank you, worked perfectly :)